# Whereafter or where after, one or two words?

Tags: word-usage, orthography, phrase-usage

If I Google the word *whereafter*, multiple online dictionaries claim it is one word.
However, if I type it in Microsoft Outlook, then spellcheck insists that it is two words.
"Grammarly" seems to accept both. Is there a definitive rule? Is it *whereafter* or *where after*?

Comment: Please add the link to the Grammarly article. But never blindly believe the Microsoft spellchecker.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not an article, I was referring to the Grammarly browser plug-in spelling/grammar checker.

Comment: Consider: "Who will be where after the course ends?" This sentence, pointing to the fact that once the students finish the course, generally move to different jobs in different places, rhetorically states that it is not possible to tell. HTH.

Comment: We will not find the phrase *where after* in a dictionary because it is just a pair or individual words and not a set phrase or idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Whereafter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whereafter) is a  formal way to say:

> - *After which:*
>
>   - dinner was taken at a long wooden table, whereafter we sipped liqueurs in front of a roaring fire. (ODO)

- The term is just one single word, as two separate words usage and meaning are different as shown in 
  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=where%20after%2C%20whereafter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhere%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhereafter%3B%2Cc0) (whereafter vs where after).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how meaning is different if used as two words?

Comment: I can't find examples of 'whereafter' used as two separate words meaning *after which'. As shown in Ngram, 'where after' is used in sentences like: I have seen a number of cases *where after* a death the family discovers that an ex -spouse ... Or: A similar process has also been apparent in foreign policy, *where after* the end of the Cultural Revolution....- and similar.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the dictionaries are more comphrensive than Outlook spell check. It is still valid to split into the two base words. But it is fairly formal language, which seems to have a legal usage. So the joined form would be more common.

Comment: Can you please cite a reference in support?